# Can not link to pcl library

Tags: pcl, ros-indigo, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The following code:

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <pcl_ros/point_cloud.h>
#include <pcl/point_types.h>
#include <boost/foreach.hpp>

typedef pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ> PointCloud;
void callback(const PointCloud::ConstPtr& msg)
{
  printf ("Cloud: width = %d, height = %d\n", msg->width, msg->height);
  BOOST_FOREACH (const pcl::PointXYZ& pt, msg->points)
    printf ("\t(%f, %f, %f)\n", pt.x, pt.y, pt.z);
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  ros::init(argc, argv, "sub_pcl");
  ros::NodeHandle nh;
  ros::Subscriber sub = nh.subscribe<PointCloud>("points2", 1, callback);
  ros::spin();
}
```

Which is a default tutorial on how to use PCL in ros.

My CMake:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6 FATAL_ERROR)
find_package(PCL 1.3 REQUIRED COMPONENTS common io)
include_directories(${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${PCL_LIBRARY_DIRS})
add_definitions(${PCL_DEFINITIONS})
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} ${PCL_COMMON_LIBRARIES} ${PCL_IO_LIBRARIES})
```

Which is the exact configuration recommended on the pcl official website

I still get the following linking error:

```
CMakeFiles/apsp_manifold.dir/src/apsp_manifold.cpp.o: In function `void pcl::detail::FieldMapper<pcl::PointXYZ>::operator()<pcl::fields::z>()':
/usr/include/pcl-1.7/pcl/conversions.h:106: undefined reference to `pcl::console::print(pcl::console::VERBOSITY_LEVEL, char const*, ...)'
CMakeFiles/apsp_manifold.dir/src/apsp_manifold.cpp.o: In function `void pcl::detail::FieldMapper<pcl::PointXYZ>::operator()<pcl::fields::y>()':
/usr/include/pcl-1.7/pcl/conversions.h:106: undefined reference to `pcl::console::print(pcl::console::VERBOSITY_LEVEL, char const*, ...)'
CMakeFiles/apsp_manifold.dir/src/apsp_manifold.cpp.o: In function `void pcl::detail::FieldMapper<pcl::PointXYZ>::operator()<pcl::fields::x>()':
/usr/include/pcl-1.7/pcl/conversions.h:106: undefined reference to `pcl::console::print(pcl::console::VERBOSITY_LEVEL, char const*, ...)'
```

What do I have the above described error and how can I remove it?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/196497/can-not-link-to-pcl-library./) by [abarbarosie](https://answers.ros.org/users/20252/abarbarosie/) on ROS Answers with karma: 76 on 2014-11-02

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-11-02**:
If you're having trouble linking against PCL, you should probably ask on their mailing list rather than here. This tutorial looks **VERY** old; I suspect it isn't entirely compatible with the more recent versions of PCL.

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-11-02**:
It would also be useful to link to the PCL documentation that you're using when you report this: http://pointclouds.org/documentation/tutorials/using_pcl_pcl_config.php#using-pcl-pcl-config

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Thanks to @ahendrix pointing out that the tutorial is old. I found [this](http://wiki.ros.org/pcl/Overview) tutorial page which gave me enough insight and the linker was not complaining.

In relation to my question, apparently the issue was incompatibility of the code which is old with the library which is new. The headers are there but the object files in the library are missing.

---

Originally posted by [abarbarosie](https://answers.ros.org/users/20252/abarbarosie/) with karma: 76 on 2014-11-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

```
target_link_libraries( ... ${PCL_LIBRARIES})
```

add`${PCL_LIBRARIES}` may help

---

Originally posted by [张京林](https://answers.ros.org/users/19842/%E5%BC%A0%E4%BA%AC%E6%9E%97/) with karma: 31 on 2017-08-08

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [askkvn](https://answers.ros.org/users/40828/askkvn/) on 2020-04-30**:
Thanks a lot, it works.

I am using: `Ubuntu 18.04 LTS`, `ROS Kinetic`

Attaching my working `CMakeLists.txt` for reference.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)
project(enter_your_package_name)

find_package(catkin REQUIRED COMPONENTS
  roscpp
  rospy
  sensor_msgs
)

find_package(PCL)

catkin_package(
)

include_directories(
# include
  ${catkin_INCLUDE_DIRS}
)

include_directories(${PCL_INCLUDE_DIRS})
link_directories(${PCL_LIBRARY_DIRS})
add_definitions(${PCL_DEFINITIONS})

add_executable(file_name src/file_name.cpp)

add_dependencies(file_name ${${PROJECT_NAME}_EXPORTED_TARGETS} ${catkin_EXPORTED_TARGETS})

target_link_libraries(file_name
  ${catkin_LIBRARIES}
  ${PCL_LIBRARIES}
)
```